# change text color of selected dynamic textbox using color picker

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are at most 15 text boxes in my page which is created on the click of a button.
What I want is to change the text color of only the text-box which is "SELECTED"; the color of all the other text boxes should not change.

Currently, I have a text color changer slider which changes the color of all the text boxes.

Click here to [download](http://www.cloud9-spa.com/download/stack.rar) the source code.

Comment: Please post the code in the question itself. There's no way I'm downloading a .rar from you.

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle instead of giving source code.

Comment: jason i cant post the whole code in the question itself because the source code is very big and is not feasible.
thats why i provided the link to download the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:
    Include jscolor.js in your index file. You can see more demo and download also from this link http://jscolor.com/try.php

```
   <div>
         <?php
        or($i=0;$i<15;$i++){?>
            <div id="txt_add<?php echo $i; ?>" onclick="get_current_text(<?php echo $i; ?>);">
                            <div id="f<?php echo $i+1; ?>" class="bring_front"><span style="cursor:move"><input type="text" **class="box color"** placeholder="Sample text <?php echo $i+1; ?>" style="border:none; background:none; width:87px; margin-left:6px;" maxlength="10" onchange="set_color(<?php echo $i; ?>);"/></span></div>
               </div>
               <?php }?>                        
</div>

and put this code in javascript:    
 function set_color(txtid)
{
    $("#txt_add"+txtid+" input").css('color','#'+this.color);
    //document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].style.backgroundColor = '#'+this.color
}
function get_current_text(id)
{
    $("#prod div input").css("background-color","white");
    $("#txt_add"+id+" input").css('background-color',"green");  $("#txt_add"+id+" input").css('color',"red");
}
```

Edit: 1)Change input class from box to box color
         2) put this in input onchange="set_color();"
         3) Put set_color function in your script

Comment: jagruti thank you very much for your response, it changes the background color of text box to green and text color to red as soon as i click on it. but i have to use the color picker so that user can select what color he/she want to instead of just one single static color which i have defined.

Comment: well thanx for your effort, your code is working. i also tried with the same JS and it is working fine.
although your method is far far different from mine.
both method is correct.
thanx again for your precious time.
:)

Comment: Jagruti i have some other issue also related to corePHP
will you help sort out that issue?
thanx in advance

Comment: Heyyy, the function which you are using is Captures the whole screen (http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagegrabscreen.php)not for some part of screen so please visit this link may ne it will help you http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?385497-Easy-Screen-Capture-Class-Capture-Screen-Desktop-Region-Form-or-Controls

Comment: first link u gave is for VB and another link is not helpful for me. it show some method which is not working for me. :(